# Create a scale in a given mode (e.g. lydian or dorian) with lilypond

Tags: lilypond

How do I create a scale in a given mode (e.g. lydian or dorian) with lilypond?

I've seen that the scales are defined in [scale-definitions-init.ly](https://github.com/lilypond/lilypond/blob/v2.25.8/ly/scale-definitions-init.ly) and I've tried to apply `\set Staff.keyAlterations` but I'm not sure if this is the right way.

Basically I'd like to get something similar to `music21`'s scales:

```
>>> sc = scale.LydianScale(pitch.Pitch('f'))
>>> [str(p) for p in sc.pitches]
['F4', 'G4', 'A4', 'B4', 'C5', 'D5', 'E5', 'F5']

>>> sc = scale.LydianScale(pitch.Pitch('c'))
>>> [str(p) for p in sc.pitches]
['C4', 'D4', 'E4', 'F#4', 'G4', 'A4', 'B4', 'C5']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’m not 100% sure what you want, but does this help?

```
scale =
#(define-music-function (dur len root scale)
   (ly:duration? (number? #f) ly:pitch? number-pair-list?)
   (if (not len) (set! len (length scale)))
   (let ((basescale (make-music 'SequentialMusic
                                'elements
                                (map (lambda (i)
                                       (make-music 'NoteEvent
                                                   'pitch (ly:make-pitch
                                                           (quotient i (length scale))
                                                           (remainder i (length scale))
                                                           (assoc-get (remainder i (length scale)) scale))
                                                   'duration dur))
                                     (iota len)))))
     (transpose (ly:make-pitch 0 0) root basescale)))

\scale 4 8 d'\lydian
```